# Screen hiccups after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: drivers, video, 20.04

After upgrading to 20.04 on my Thinkpad X250 I started facing issues with random screen hiccups. It seems that the screen is freezing instantly every second or so. I've tried to change the refresh rate, but it didn't help. I'm assuming that the issue is with the driver of the graphics card. I also tried to reinstall the driver with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel` but it didn't improve.

Another issue I noticed is that if I open the applications screen, I cannot scroll down to the next page of applications. Even if I try to go to an app on the second screen with the arrow keys, I am still seeing the first screen, although I can actually choose the apps on the lower screens.

The above make me believe that something wasn't installed properly during the upgrade.

Any ideas?